# innitiate an numpy.array and append/concatenate with no sucess

Tags: arrays, numpy

I try to innitiate an array of size [] and want to append it as require ... but without sucess, this is my code:

```
y= np.array([])
...
x= 0.055
y.append(x)
```

and I get 
"AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'concatenate'"

Comment: Use `np.append(y, x)` instead.

Comment: Don't use `np.append`.  Stick with lists if you are using the iterative append model.  If you want an array, create that at the end with one function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the code should be

```
    y = np.append(y,x)
```